# GNOME fallback session has both top and bottom panels also unity launcher running through them

Tags: 12.04, unity, unity-2d, gnome-classic

I have the GNOME fallback session installed and when I log into it I get both the top and bottom panels and also the Unity launcher and it overlays both and makes it look funny. It is the Unity 2D session's launcher that shows up. [image]

I was wondering how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Can i get some screeshot please.

Comment: I added a screenshot of this

Comment: Just ask, can you meta+alt right click on the bottom panel?

Comment: I can do that with the bottom panel but when I log into the classic session (No effects) and I can meta+alt right click on both bottom and top panels

Answer (score 0):

Re-installing gnome-session-fallback worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove gnome-session-fallback && sudo apt-get install gnome-session fallback
```